# Trying to convert image from rectangle shape to circular

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

i am trying to convert imageview into 60px circular image but its not happening ...

the way i am trying is...

```
File imgFile = new  File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "MyCameraApp" + File.separator + "profile_" + userId + ".jpg");

        if(imgFile.exists()){
            Bitmap correctBmp=null;

              ExifInterface exif;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(imgFile.getPath());
                  int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                    int angle = 0;

                    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                           angle = 90;
                    }
                    else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                           angle = 180;
                    }
                    else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                           angle = 270;
                    }

                    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
                    mat.postRotate(90);



                  Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(imgFile), null, null);
                  /* correctBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), mat, true);*/
                  correctBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(),  bmp1.getConfig());
                  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(correctBmp);
                   Paint paint = new Paint();
                   paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                   paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bmp1, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
                   canvas.drawRoundRect((new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight())), 10, 10, paint);
                   profileImage.setImageBitmap(correctBmp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                  }
```

it is loading rectangle shape image so what should i do ?

Please help...

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18378873/1665507

Comment: why not add a circular background to the image using xml android:background

Comment: thats not a good idea actually i did that but not getting better look... @IllegalArgument

Comment: I beg to differ use shape oval and provide radius if you know the height of the image then you can specify corner radius half of the image height doing this will not require any java code so I think its worth a shot

Comment: ok i got you Thanks @Illegal Argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my code and it works for me:

```
public class ImageHelper {

public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    //Bitmap _bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 60, 60, false);
    //return _bmp;
    return output;
}
```

}

just create a class and put this code in it, and then you can use it like this:

```
// create round image
public void setCircularImage() {

    ImageView imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Bitmap bitImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon_person);
    ImageHelper imgHlp = new ImageHelper();
    imv.setImageBitmap(imgHlp.getCroppedBitmap(bitImg));   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For that the better option you have universal image loader.
you can easily make image rounded with create an option of image loader

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(50))
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_app)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.camera)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .build();
```

you can take more reference [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 1):

see below link :-

[Add border to getRoundedCornerBitmap android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753544/add-border-to-getroundedcornerbitmap-android/23753635#23753635)

or use Universal Loader

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.cacheInMemory(true)
.cacheOnDisc(true)
.displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(60))
.build();//value which you want to round

ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Uri.parse(imgByURL).toString(), imgThumb, options);
```