# Android corner crop bitmap image with static bg color

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-listview, bitmap

[image]

The pink image you see, is a square, initially, and want its top right corner to be cropped off.

What is the correct way to approach this problem, the bitmap so generated will be used for a Grid View, will generating a custom bitmap from a source image be a bottle neck when doing such operation during getView() in the adapter?

One better approach is to use drawable bg, and add padding, however, i'm unsuccessful with filling the corners.

Another approach is re-drawing the bitmap with the required bg, however, i'm unable to corner crop.

**Update**

I found a simple way to do this, inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame)

Comment: Do you mean you are having the red image and you need to draw blue border and the corner with tick mark on it?

Comment: @VinayakBevinakatti yes

Comment: Check my answer, please comment on that if you don't get what I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two images, one red (which is inner part of the image) and one blue (which is outer part of the image). The blue image have border and the corner with transparent inner body. And use Imageview with `android:background="@drawable/redImage"` and `android:src="@drawable/blueImage"`. Using this you can apply the blue border with corner to any image on your grid.

In Imageview `src` is a foreground image and `background` is a background image.

Comment: i get your point, however, can you suggest a programmable approach so that, the square redImage can be corner cropped? In this way, we can have variable background like blue green etc.

Comment: You can use Canvas for it, but it will be tedious. Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17045266/28557

Answer (score 0):

You can create 9-patch image from your blue border with corner. And than use

```
<FrameLayout
     ...
     android:foreground="@drawable/blue_border">
    <ImageView 
        android:src = "@drawable/red_image"
        ... />
</FrameLayout>
```